# Redirect all but some specific traffic via .htaccess..?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I have a file at `example.com/DesktopModules/SubscriptionSignup/Tools/IPNHandler.aspx` that needs to be rewritten so that it actually runs `example.com/paypal-ipn-handler.php`.

All other traffic, though, should be redirected to `another-example.com`.

I'm using this in my .htaccess file:

```
# Rewrite IPNHandler.aspx to paypal-ipn-handler.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Tools/IPNHandler.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.com/paypal-ipn-handler.php [P]
</IfModule>

#Redirect all other traffic to new domain.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.another-example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, that's redirected everything including the URL that should stay at this domain, but get re-written to the PHP file.

For example, with the above in place, I would expect that traffic to `example.com/DesktopModules/SubscriptionSignup/Tools/IPNHandler.aspx` would remain at `example.com`, but run the PHP script instead.  This is not happening, though.  It's getting redirected to `another-example.com/..../IPNHandler.aspx` and gives me a 404, of course.

Any information about how I can adjust this so that my rewrite works and stays on the original domain, but all other traffic gets redirected would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Actually, I commented out the redirect to see if my rewrite was working, and it's actually giving me a 404, but when I hit the paypal-ipn-handler.php directly I get the output I expect.

So it seems I need more help than I thought, please, and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site soot .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule Tools/IPNHandler\.aspx$ /paypal-ipn-handler.php [L,NC]

#Redirect all other traffic to new domain.
RewriteRule !^paypal-ipn-handler\.php$ https://www.another-example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

There is no need to use `P` flag here as you just want an internal rewrite.

Condition `!^paypal-ipn-handler\.php$` will redirect everything except `/paypal-ipn-handler.php`.

Make sure to use a new browser to test or test after you completely clear browser cache.